# What are the differences between a, A and Z format codes of pack function in PHP

Tags: php, string-formatting, pack

What are the differences between `a`, `A`, and `Z` format codes of the `pack('format', ...$args)` function in PHP?

### Test

I have tested all three in the following manner and they produced almost the **same result**:

```
$s = ' Testing... ';

var_export( pack('a*', $s) === $s ); // true
var_export( pack('A*', $s) === $s ); // true
var_export( pack('Z*', $s) === $s ); // false (because it just adds a "\0" at the end)

// So in case of 'Z*' if I trim the last "\0" it's also the same
var_export( rtrim(pack('Z*', $s), "\0") === $s ); // true
```

**Note:** regarding `Z` I now only understand that it is appending a `null character` or `"\0"` at the end of the string, but I still want to know if it is doing anything else.

The above are the most confusing parts for me, but if someone describe `x`, `X`, and `@` as well, I will really appreciate it.

Comment: As for `Z`: *"The "Z" code was added with equivalent functionality to "a" for Perl compatibility."*

Comment: @deceze so otherwise it's not doing anything else other than what I said?

Comment: Not with the way you're using it. I'm not too deep into `pack`, but `a` and `A` appear to *pad* a string to a desired length; since you're not specifying any desired length, they do nothing for all intents and purposes. See https://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html.